# How can I make jQuery change navigation color on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, colors, navigation

I'm working on this template, and I want the navigation to change color once the user begins scrolling. I've been playing around with jQuery, and so far I've gotten the functionality down pat. But! I would like the color to be able to change to a very specific color, in this instance a HEX or RGBA color, not just standard name colors (i.e, blue, red, black, etc). This is my code below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var a = $(".navbar").offset().top;

            $(document).scroll(function(){
                if($(this).scrollTop() > a)
                {   
                   $('.navbar').css({"background":"black"});
                } else {
                   $('.navbar').css({"background":"none"});
                }
            });
        });
```

Where I change the .navbar with the .css jquery selector, how can I change the background color to a hex or rgba instead of just black or red or whatnot? I'm really stumped here. The code works well, and once the user scrolls past the header, it changes color from transparent to black, but I want the black to be this hex code #04B297, and I'm not really sure on how to proceed. Any pointers?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey. Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost I would change the css declaration from `background` to `background-color`. With `background` you're changing any other background properties you might have like `background-size`, `background-position`, etc.

Since you're only trying to go from a predefined CSS color to that of a HEX color you simply just put the value inside as you did with `black`.

**Note:** You'll also need to change your the css declaration in your else block from `none` to `transparent` as `none` is not a correct background-color value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = $(".navbar").offset().top;

  $(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > a) {
      $('.navbar').css({"background-color":"#04B297"});
    } else {
      $('.navbar').css({"background-color":"transparent"});
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

.navbar {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 60px;
}

.navbar--dark {
  background-color: #04B297
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar"></div>
```

I would suggest assigning these color states to their own modifier class. You get a little bit of a performance boost and imo it's a little more managable.  With this in place you could simply use `toggleClass()` to toggle the dark background color. The second parameter is the boolean based value it uses to determine when to toggle.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = $(".navbar").offset().top;
    
  $(document).scroll(function(){
    $('.navbar').toggleClass('navbar--dark', $(this).scrollTop() > a);
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

.navbar {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 60px;
}

.navbar--dark {
  background-color: #04B297
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar"></div>
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, couldn't get the classes in my css to work though, but the jQuery itself was perfect! Many thanks!

Comment: Great to hear! Don't forget to mark this as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use prop() instead of Css

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
            var a = $(".navbar").offset().top;

            $(document).scroll(function(){
                if($(this).scrollTop() > a)
                {   
                   $('.navbar').prop({"background","#FFF000"});
                } else {
                   $('.navbar').prop({"background","#333333"});
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

only change your script where you written your in-line css

```
$('.navbar').css({"background":"black"});
```

change

```
background=>background-color
```

Answer (score 0):

Some good ideas mentioned above. Another approach is to use the navigation bar:

> your route

as then it is presented to your user your intent of where **they** are on you application / website.

```
 <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">
                <img src="img/conceptco_home_logo.png" />
            </a>
```

Notice the **#page-top** route on the anchor tag.

```
<body id="page-top">
```

That's where the route will take you. If your URL has **#page-top** in it, the page will automatically scroll there, retrospectively if you perform a click event on the anchor tag in JQuery then it will move to that location.

For the colour, you can have a CSS class that represents the different colours then add / remove the css property in Jquery.

Here is a working example in a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Ashworx-South-Africa/Concept-Co-Website/blob/master/src/index.html)